# C# casting to object in interface generic

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

i have a problem that I do not understand about casting in interfaces with generic (probably because covariance and contravariance are not completly clear to me at the moment).

I have an Interface where i define a getter and setter that should accept anything in a typed way (no object as type)
Eg :

```
public interface IDummy <T>
{
     int SomeCommonMethod() ;
     T   Anything { get; set; }
}
```

Now i define some concretes implementation of interface defined before.

```
public class MyStrObj : IDummy <string>
{
     private string _stirngVal = string.Empty ;

     public int SomeCommonMethod() 
     {
         return 0 ;
     }

     public string Anything 
     { 
         get { return _stirngVal  ; } 
         set { _stirngVal = value ; }
     }
}

public class MyFileObj : IDummy <File>
{
     private File _file = null ;

     public int SomeCommonMethod() 
     {
         return 0 ;
     }

     public File Anything 
     { 
         get { return  _file ; } 
         set { _file = value ; }
     }
}
```

At time all works as expected, but now when try to use this two object their behaviour start becoming confusing for me.

I try to define an object that should be able to consume both previous classes (no matter which type they has in their generics, what matter is that they are IDummy).

```
public class Consumer
{
     public static void Consume ( IDummy<object> obj )
     {
          //SOME CODE HERE.
     }
}
```

Now if i try this code :

```
MyStrObj obj = new MyStrObj () ;
Consumer.Consume ( obj ) ;
```

then compiler notice to me that there are some invalid parameters over Consume method calling (obj sure), but there is not an implicit cast here?

If i try this way instead :

```
MyStrObj obj = new MyStrObj () ;
Consumer.Consume ( (IDummy<object>)obj ) ;
```

compiler seems to work as I suppose it should (at time I have not tested if the two calls are equivalent).

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help me to understand this behaviour, and sorry for my english (is not my language).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `IDummy<T>` is not covariant. That is why the implicit conversion of such does not work. If it were covariant, the conversion from more specific generic type to the more general one would work. However in your example you cannot make your interface covariant `IDummy<out T>`, since it has a property setter with your generic parameter.

Comment: Thanks this clarify (and simplify) a lot the situation.In my above example (and real case too) the generics could be only object so setter is not strictly needed (what i would set is inside the object reference not the object reference itself)

Answer (score 2):

The method in your `Consumer` class needs to be generic.

```
public class Consumer
{
     public static void Consume<T> ( IDummy<T> obj )
     {
          //SOME CODE HERE.
     }
}
```

Then you can do

```
var foo = new MyStrObj();
foo.Anything = "Hello";
Consumer.Consume(foo);
```

Comment: You might want to mention that `IDummy<string>` is not derived from `IDummy<object>` We really shouldn't be casting from one to another.

Comment: `public class Consumer
{
     IDummy<T> myObj; //why does this not work?
     public static void Consume<T> ( IDummy<T> obj )
     {
         myObj=obj; //why does this not work?
     }
}`

Comment: @AnkitKhanal - Because to have a field with a generic type the class has to also be generic. Otherwise there's no type available to bind to the type parameter in the field declaration.

Answer (score -1):

In order to achieve what you described using covariance you need to amend your interface to make it covariant.

Covariance allows you to assign more specific types to less specific. This is possible however only for the classes that only return your objects of the template type.

Hence in your interface you need to remove the setter ant mark the T as covariant using the keyword `out`. You can keep the setter on the classes that implement it though. So your interface would have to look like this:

```
public interface IDummy<out T>
{
    int SomeCommonMethod();
    T Anything { get; }
}
```

Your `MyStrObj`, `MyFileObj` and `Consumer` classes can stay as they are. After the change you can utilize the covariance when calling the Consume method.

```
    MyStrObj obj = new MyStrObj();
    obj.Anything = "My string";
    Consumer.Consume(obj);
```

Comment: +0: Not going to work - there is r/w property in the interface.